# Nginx throws 403 Forbidden nginx/1.11.8 errors despite using all answers from serverfault

Tags: nginx, centos7, selinux

I have `CentOs 7.3` and `Nginx 1.11.8` and `PHP-FPM 7.0`

This is a clean install, and everytime I get the above error page if I change the root for the nginx dir from `/usr/share/nginx/html` to anything.

This time I changed it to /var/www/html.

Now I am getting the error.

I have given the html dir `chmod 775` and then `777` to no avail.
I have also made `chown -R nginx:nginx html/`

These don't work. BUT, if I disabled SELinux as `setenforce 0` everything works.

I don't want to disable selinux entirely due to this issue, but it's driving me nuts.

chmoding with www-data gives me this error.

```
[simon@localhost www]$ chown -R www-data:www-data html
chown: invalid user: âwww-data:www-dataâ
```

Which I think is fair, since I have no user named www-data. Nginx is running under nginx user.

`tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` gives me this:

```
2017/01/07 22:37:03 [error] 3336#3336: *1 open() "/var/www/html/nginx.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /nginx.html HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2017/01/07 22:37:06 [error] 3336#3336: *1 "/var/www/html/index.php" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

So, it is still a permission issue, probably tied to SELinux VLC thing.. I'm not sure.

Here is my ls -lZ output.

```
[simon@localhost html]$ ls -lZ
-rwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0   index.php
-rwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:vmblock_t:s0   nginx.html
```

Answer (score 2):

How on earth did you get those bizarre SELinux contexts? Those are not the default contexts.

Anyway, you should use `restorecon` to change the SELinux contexts back to the defaults, on all of your web content. For example:

```
restorecon -r -v /var/www/html
```

You also should *never* chmod 777 anything, not even for "testing".

Comment: I applied the context but it didn't change anything. I still get the same SELinux contexts. also, I have a folder called `www` in my windows, full path is: `C:/www` I am mounting this folder to `/var/www` I run `mount -t vboxsf www /var/www` aside from these I haven't done much, it's a clean install. Also, the turning of selinux, and chmoding 777 is just out of distress, I am asking this question so I can avoid doing that :)

Comment: @user7342807 vboxsf? Don't do that. It doesn't work with SELinux. And it's not professional.

Comment: Hmm.. I have used it for 2 years, always switching off selinux. I don't know any other alternatives. Is the command wrong, or do I have to use other application to share host folder?

Comment: You don't "share host folder".

Comment: I meant, share as as in mount. When I develop web applications in my Linux server, I need to edit them on windows.

Comment: @user7342807 Then create a SSH-user with access limited to that specific web-folder (not your server root) and use something like FileZilla to synchronize your local files with your server files. In case you're talking about a production server: **Don't ever use online servers for development.** In that case better use a local XAMPP.

Comment: @Broco I think you misread something, as my question has nothing to do with SSH, or user privileges. This is SElinux issue

Comment: @user7342807 Yes sorry, I came here from your other post :P